# Residue at infinity for different functions

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-principal-value

My main question is how can I identify that f(z)=(z+i)^-1 or other functions have a non-zero residue at infinity. The reason for confusion is I am taught that if f(z)~z^-2 as z tends to infinity then we have a removable singularity at z=infinity. Would this tells us that if f(z)~z^-1 as z tends to infinity, then this function would have a simple pole a infinity for all function that tend the same way and what would this mean about functions that tend off as z^-3 etc. Hope this question makes sense.

Comment: You can use all your knowledge about residues, isolated singularities and principal parts with $\frac{-1}{w^2}f\left(\frac{1}{w}\right)dw$ at $w=0$. For example, if we want to see the nature of the singularity of $f(z)dz=\frac{dz}{z}$ at $z=\infty$, we study $\frac{-1}{w^2}wdw=\frac{-dw}{w}$ at $w=0$. You can see that it has a pole of order $1$ and the residue is $-1$.

Comment: But what would be the specific reason in to use the sub z=1/w for this case but not for the case of  f(z)~z^-2 as z tends to infinity. I hope this makes sense, thanks for the help!

Comment: The same with $f(z)dz=\frac{1}{z^2}dz$. We get $\frac{-1}{w^2}w^2dw=-dw$. So, it is a regular point, or removable if you want.

Comment: Ah okay perfect that's solved my issued, thank you very much Boxwood!